# AES_cbc_encrypt is not decrypted when we call c++ function from JNI to get decrypted data

Tags: c++, password-encryption

I am using `AES_CBC_Encrypt(...)` to encrypt and decrypt tha data, when we use `AES_CBC_Encrypt` to encrypt and decrypt in c++ it working fine but when need to call c++ function from java to get decrypted data (real one like Password) but when we call c++ function throught JNI at that time we not get proper out out.

We pass only argument throught java and we get proper argument in c++ and get the proper encypted token from text file from where we save the encrypted password but after decrypted it show different .
we also use padding

```
AES_cbc_encrypt (Inputbuf, outputbuf, ilen, &aesDecryKey, ivv, AES_DECRYPT);
if (length > AES_BLOCK_SIZE && (length % AES_BLOCK_SIZE == 0))
{
  length = length - AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
  memset(pObuf + length, 0, AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
}
cout << " password is " << outputbuf << endl;
```

Comment: What is `length` and `pObuf `? Why are you doing the `if` block?

Comment: length of outoutbuf or pObuf is 256, if block check only length of outoutbuf or pObuf , we write only for check , it give same out put without if condition,there is no need of if we write only for check. if you have a solution of my answer please help me. it not give proper out put when we call by JNI.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see where the variable `length` is set. perhaps `ilen` and `length` are supposed to be the same and there is a typo.

What is the reason for the `if` code? If it is to remove a padding block it is incorrect to remove it, see PKCS#7 padding [documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7). If the input data is a multiple of the block size and there is PKCS#7 (or PKCS#5) padding a full block of padding **must be added**.

Comment: can you suggest me why encryption and decryption is properly work on c++ and same function is calling from JNI to decrypt it not working properly ,please ignore if condition , ilen is length of outputbuf .

Comment: You have not supplied correct code,` length` and `ilen`, and the declaration of `pObuf`. Remove  the `if` section. provide test inputs, actual output and correct output as hex dumps. Correct the code and add the additional information to the question. As for the C++, different encryption functions are being used with different default options so no guess can be made.

Comment: I have remove the if condition , we pass only key if key present it take the encrypted data from text file after that we perform the decryption task , we check the length of " outputbuf " at time of c++ and JNI ,it show same size but at time of decryption it no perform correct decryption.

Comment: If you want help please provide the question corrections and the information requested in my prior comment.